# Proving a matrix is unitary given another matrix is skew-adjoint

Tags: matrices, adjoint-functors

I know that for a matrix $Q$ to be unitary, then $Q^\star = Q^{-1}$.
If we're given that $(I - A)$ is invertible, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is an n x n skew-adjoint matrix that is, $A^\star = -A = \bar{A^{T}}$, how would we show that
$$U = (I + A)(I - A)^{-1}$$ is unitary?
I found $U^{-1}$ and $U^{\star}$ and they were equal, but that was under naive assumptions.
These were the assumptions (and I'm not sure if it's true, can anyone confirm) that I had.
$$\text{1.} \qquad \overline{(I-A)^{-1}} = (\bar{I} - \bar{A})^{-1}. \\ \text{2.} \quad (I+A) \quad \text{is invertible.}$$ Can someone confirm if these are true in this case, and in general, and if not, how would I have done this question?

Comment: For an arbitrary matrix $A$, the fact that $(I-A)$ is invertible does not imply that $(I+A)$ is invertible as well. There's some work to show there that is specific to this problem.

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the eigenvalues of unitary and skew-adjoint matrices? How does adding or subtracting the the identity matrix change the eigenvalues?

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks. We actually didn't touch on the eigenvalues of a skew-adjoint matrix I think, we were  just given this assumption of the matrix $A$. Would there be any other way to prove $I+A$ is invertible, besides the eigenvalues? (Maybe showing that if $(I+A)v = 0$ for all $v \in V$ implies $v = 0$, then we must have invertibility?

Comment: @PaulWoch: Have you seen that self-adjoint matrices have only real eigenvalues?  $I+A = -i(iI+iA)$, and $iA$ is self-adjoint so it cannot have $-i$ as an eigenvalue, hence $iI+iA$ is invertible, hence $I+A$ is.  Showing that $(I+A)v=0$ implies $v=0$ is exactly showing that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue for $A$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Oo, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of (1) and (2) do you want $((I-A)^{-1})^*=(I-A^*)^{-1}=(I+A)^{-1}$?

It is true and easy to show that if $B$ is invertible, then so is $B^{*}$, and $(B^{-1})^*=(B^{*})^{-1}$.  Just multiply: $B^{*}(B^{-1})^*=(B^{-1}B)^*=I^*=I$ and similarly in the other order.  In your case, that means if you already know that $I-A$ is invertible, then so is $I+A=(I-A)^*$, and $(I+A)^{-1}=((I-A)^{-1})^*$.

But why is $I-A$ (and hence $I+A$) invertible in the first place?  Because $A$ is skew-adjoint, so all of its eigenvalues are purely imaginary.

Comment: Thanks. To show that $B^\star$ is invertible, we let $det(B) = a$ for $a \ne 0$, so $det(B^\star) = \frac{1}{\bar{a}}$ right?

Comment: @Paul: I don't advise that.  $B^*$ is invertible because $B^*(B^{-1})^*=(B^{*})^{-1}B^*=I$.  That is, it is invertible because of the definition and because it has an inverse we can easily demonstrate. If you want to use the determinant however it would be $\overline a$, not $\frac1{\overline a}$.  That would work but has the disadvantage of not generalizing to infinite dimensions (if that matters to you).

Comment: I was referring to your "then so is $B^\star$" statement (I interpreted as you saying assume $B$ is invertible, then this implies $B^\star$ is invertible). Correct me if I'm wrong.  
Also I believe it should be $\frac{1}{\bar{a}}$ shouldn't it? Since the determinant of the transpose of a matrix is just 1/determinant, and I assume taking the complex conjugate will take the complex conjugate of that as well?

Comment: @Paul: I have pointed out in the answer and again in the above comment exactly why $B^*$ is invertible, because $(B^{-1})^*$ is its inverse. Multiply them to show that, as seen in the answer (for one direction).  But it's fine to use the determinant too.  No, the determinant of the transpose is equal to the determinant, not the reciprocal of the determinant.  Expanding on a row or column gives the same thing.  You're thinking of the determinant of the inverse.  The complex conjugate part is correct because the conjugate of a sum or product of numbers is the sum or product of the conjugates.

Comment: Come to think of it, using the determinant is worse not just for not generalizing but because it doesn't tell you that $(B^*)^{-1}=(B^{-1})^*$, so it would be an extra step at least.  In any case, as the last part of my answer indicates, here $I\pm A$ are invertible for the same reason: $\pm 1$ are not eigenvalues of the skew-adjoint matrix $A$.

Comment: Much appreciated!